# Python - web framework and form localization (number formatting)

Tags: python, wsgi

Are there any frameworks aside from Django that can easily handle localization of forms? (number formatting specifically)

I've looked at Pyramid and Flask but their documentation talks mostly about translations and not number formatting. Does anybody have any experience with this and could possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: @jterrace - Some queries that I'd like to do don't seem to be easily done in Django (from what I've read so far)

Answer (score 2):

Django is an all-in-one package, while Pyramid and Flask give you more flexibility.

Take a look at the [Babel project](http://babel.edgewall.org/); you can localize your forms using that package with ease.

Comment: The documentation regarding forms in Pyramid and Flask both mention (if I am not mistaken) Babel for doing translations but they don't touch number formatting. I'm a bit new to Python - could you possibly give me an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: The Babel documentation has [some examples](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/numbers.html).